# imagemagick: how to get image size after resize?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm resizing my image using imagemagick, however, I'm not specifying the exact size:

convert $filename -resize 1080000@ -quality 100 $reduced_filename

it's resized within a bound, now the problem is, after resize, the size in the EXIF is no longer correct, and I don't have a clue of calculating the new size (e.g. percentage resize can let me calculate new size based on percentage).

So is there a way to get image size after resizing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick's "convert" command to access the image dimensions with a command like this...

```
convert $filename -format "%[w]x%[h]" info:
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this...

First create a start image 1024x768:

```
convert -size 1024x768 xc:black start.jpg
```

Now resize, and output new size info in one fell swoop:

```
convert start.jpg -resize 50% -format "%wx%h" -write info: result.jpg
512x384
```